# error in running openCV/samples/cpp/lkdemo.cpp

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to run the OpenCV based Lucas kande code :

```
OpenCV/samples/cpp/lkdemo.cpp
```

I am using

```
opencv 3.0 version 
Visual studio :2012
Platform: x64
```

I am able to run the code by giving *.avi input.
I can see the output as a same input .
There are no tracking points/arrows I can see .
I can see following messages on my console :

```
This is a demo of Lukas-Kanade optical flow lkdemo(),
Using OpenCV version 3.0.0
It uses camera by default, but you can provide a path to video as an argument.

Hot keys:
        ESC - quit the program
        r - auto-initialize tracking
        c - delete all the points
        n - switch the "night" mode on/off
To add/remove a feature point click it

Corrupt JPEG data: 6 extraneous bytes before marker 0xdb
Corrupt JPEG data: 28 extraneous bytes before marker 0xdb
Corrupt JPEG data: 6 extraneous bytes before marker 0xdb
Corrupt JPEG data: 2 extraneous bytes before marker 0xdb
Corrupt JPEG data: 2905 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd5
Corrupt JPEG data: 1170 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd2
```

When I give any one of the input as r/c/n ,Code is crashing .
Can anyone tell me How can I see the tracking output on screen .

Answer (score 0):

Try using the code "as is."

After `namedWindow( "LK Demo", 1 );` add `waitKey(1000);`

So that it becomes,

```
namedWindow( "LK Demo", 1 );    
waitKey(1000);     
setMouseCallback( "LK Demo", onMouse, 0 );
```

Try building afterwards.